# Wild card for end of line in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

My match pattern has 4 parts :

```
    <1st part><2nd part><3rd part><4th part>

    Here,
     <1st part> = Fixed string "Fedora"
     <2nd part> = A 2 digit number "[0-9][0-9]"
     <3rd part> = Followed by a ":" symbol.
     <4th part> = one or more strings till the end of the current line. 

NOTE : <4th part> ends with the end of current line and contains only alphabets.
```

**I've reached till here :**

```
Fedora[0-9][0-9]?[a-z]*[A-Z]*^l>
```

But the last part - searching the end of the line - is not yielding the expected result. Note that I'm trying to get the end of the line when Word breaks the line automatically.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Did either of the contributions solve your problem?

Comment: Yes @CindyMeister the one that you provided did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use Word's built-in `Find` to locate the end of a line that's been generated by Word's automatic layout. The only kind of "end-of-line" that can be searched is the manual line break inserted by pressing Shift+Enter. The manual line break corresponds to the special Find character `^l`.

If you need to Find and extend to the end of a line then you need to use a macro (VBA). The following sample code does what you need. Please note that with the code *as it stands* only the last occurrence of the search term will be selected when the macro finishes. You need to build the final result into it that you're looking for.

Or, simply remove the `Do While` and `Loop` lines and the macro will find the first term.

```
Sub FindThenToEndOfLine()
    Dim r As Range, rDoc As Word.Range
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    bFound = True
    Set r = ActiveDocument.content
    Set rDoc = r.Duplicate

    r.Find.ClearFormatting
    Do While bFound
        With r.Find
            .text = "Fedora[0-9][0-9]:[a-z]*[A-Z]*" 
            .Forward = True
            .wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            bFound = .Execute
        End With

        If bFound Then
            r.Select
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=True
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you need:

Find = Fedora[0-9]{2}:*^l

or:

Find = Fedora[0-9]{2}:*[^l^13]

Comment: That improved the pattern. But its still not matching the "end of the line".

Comment: Well, we can only work with what you've provided, which includes your own 'end-of-line' ^l character, which indicates the presence of a manual line break. You cannot 'find' an automatic line break; paragraph breaks can be found with ^13.